# Ajax voting system vote display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a ajax voting system in one of my projects. Problem is I'm using a div with a id to display the votes. So when ever someone click vote up or down in any of the posts (there are so many posts in one page. it is a php loop) it always end up displaying in the 1st div. This is my code

```
$(function() {
    $(".vote").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;
        var parent = $(this);
        if (name == 'up') {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vote_up.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#display-vote").html(html);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vote_down.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#display-vote").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="vote-box">

<a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $PostId; ?>" name="up"></a>

<div id="display-vote"><?php echo $Votes; ?></div>

<a href="" class="answer-vote down" id="<?php echo $PostId; ?>" name="down"></a>

</div>
```

Is there is anyway that i can display votes in the correct place? Really appropriate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely just don't use an ID?

HTML:

```
<div class="vote-box">

   <a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $PostId; ?>" name="up"></a>

   <div class="display-vote"><?php echo $Votes; ?></div>

   <a href="" class="answer-vote down" id="<?php echo $PostId; ?>" name="down"></a>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
success: function(html) {
    $(this).parent().find('.display-vote').html(html);
}
```

Comment: i think in this case it will put current vote as a vote for each post on the page. in my answer i suggested to add data-id attribute

Comment: @igormilla however mine will work whatever HTML they are using. It won't put a vote on all of them, that's the whole point behind "$(this).parent().find('.display-vote')". Take the current clicked item, get it's parent and then find the element to display the HTML.

Comment: yeah, my bad. didn't get the scope of `this`. yes you are right. this will work

Comment: i tried both ways but doesn't seems to be working. maybe its because i have few more div tags wrapped around div class vote-box?

Comment: @JamieBarker it's probably not working because `$(this)` will referrer to the `$.ajax()` and not to the `$(".vote")`. You need to define `var self=this;` in the click funtion and use it instead of `this` inside of the ajax callback

Comment: @igormilla Actually the parent is defined here var `parent = $(this);`

Comment: @JamieBarker Thanks i use your code and make it work. Just had to add one extra code i just change `$(this).parent().find('.display-vote').html(html);` to `parent.parent().find('.display-vote').html(html);`

Answer (score 1):

Id attribute should be **unique**. if you have multiple elements with same id, when doing something like this `$('#myNotSoUniqueId')` will always return you first one.

As a quick solution I would recommend instead of

```
<div id="display-vote"><?php echo $Votes; ?></div>
```

have something like

```
<div class="display-vote" data-id="<?php echo $PostId; ?>">
  <?php echo $Votes; ?>
</div>
```

and in javascript to have something like this:

```
$(".display-vote[data-id='" + postId +"'])
```

to select element by specific data-id attribute